# How to print a rectangle of the following pattern

Tags: c

I need to print the following pattern in C. I have tried a lot but i am unable to make the exact pattern

```
1 1 1 1 2
3 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 4
5 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 6
```

Comment: Show your effort  and you will get help here :)

Comment: What is the functional specification of this pattern? I don't see a pattern.

Comment: Are you sure about the expected result? It is a little bit strange..

Comment: the question was asked in our exam. i m pretty sure

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, but seems interesting. Please add a few details, help us help you ;-)

Comment: @VishalKungwani I don't think that it was asked this way in your exam.

Comment: It looks like lines made up of the line number `N` where one entry is `N + 1` instead of `N`. That entry is the last or first number on that line, depending on whether the line number is odd or even. That should already be enough to come up with an implementation.

Comment: Just to be sure: you know the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32585741/edit) function?

Comment: @MOehm Good description. But how can you be sure? You answer the question "What **is** the pattern?"

Comment: @MOehm yup..when the line number is odd, the last entry gets incremented by 1 i.e i+1 and when it is even the first entry gets incremented by 1

Comment: @VishalKungwani Was the original pattern formatted in **one line**?

Comment: @VishalKungwani: Well, that already gives you all ypou need to know. What is your problem then? How to tell whether a line is odd or even? Or how to print numbers nicely? Or how to write a loop? You say that you've tried a lot. Show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i,j;
int n = 9;
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<=5;j++)
    {

        if(i%2==0)
        {
            if(j==1)
            {
                printf(" %d",i+1);
            }
            else
                printf(" %d",i);
        }
        else
        {
            if(j==5)
            {
                printf(" %d",i+1);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf(" %d",i);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
 1 1 1 1 2
 3 2 2 2 2
 3 3 3 3 4
 5 4 4 4 4
 5 5 5 5 6
 7 6 6 6 6
 7 7 7 7 8
 9 8 8 8 8
 9 9 9 9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple by loops could be -

```
  #include<stdio.h>
 int main(void)
 {
     int i,j;
     for(i=1;i<6;i++)
    { 
        if (i%2==0){                 // if i is even 
        printf("%d",i+1);            // print i+1
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){            // then print i 4 times
            printf("%d",i);
           }
        }
       else{                        // case when i is odd
           for(j=0;j<4;j++){        // print i 4 times 
               printf("%d",i);
            }
          printf("%d",i+1);         // at last print i+1
         }
       printf("\n");
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Demo -https://ideone.com/KSDBjG

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution.

```
#define MAX_ROW 5
#define MAX_COL 5

int main ()
{
    int row,col;
    int matrix[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL];

    for (row=0; row<MAX_ROW; row++)
    {
        for (col=0; col<MAX_COL; col++)
        {
            if (col== MAX_COL-1)
            {
                if(row%2)
                    matrix[row][col] = row+1;
                else
                    matrix[row][col] = row+2;
            }
            else if (col == 0)
            {
                if (row%2)
                    matrix[row][col] = row+2;
                else
                    matrix[row][col] = row+1;
            }
            else
            {
                matrix[row][col] = row+1;
            }
        }
    }

    for (row=0; row<MAX_ROW; row++)
    {
        for (col=0; col<MAX_COL; col++)
        {
            printf("%d ", matrix[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i,j;
for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
    int special=i+1;
    if(i%2==1)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=4;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",i);
        }
        printf("%d\n",special);
    }
    else if(i%2==0)
    {
        printf("%d ",special);
        for(j=1;j<=4;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",i);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
}
```

This code's output for size five is:

```
1 1 1 1 2
3 2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 4
5 4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 6
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that you are looking for something more general:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int dimension = 5;

    for( int i = 1 ; i <= dimension ; i++ )
    {
        for( int j = 1 ; j <= dimension ; j++ )
            std::cout << i + (j == 1+((dimension-1)*(i%2))) ?  (i%2)*1 : 0;

        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output with dimension = 5:

```
11112
32222
33334
54444
55556
```

Output with dimension = 7:

```
1111112
3222222
3333334
5444444
5555556
7666666
7777778
```

You can check it out online [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d21fcdf16ae03e9)

Good luck!